# How to provide a list as parameter in apache isis

Tags: isis

I have to call an api in isis and pass list of objects as parameter using parameterlayout. When I try to provide the parameter as list it throws error.

```
@Action()
    @CollectionLayout(named = "Add text fields")
    @MemberOrder(name = "Text field values",sequence = "3")     
    public List<TextField> addTextFieldValues(
            @ParameterLayout(named="Text field list")
            @Parameter(optionality=Optionality.OPTIONAL)
            final List<TextField> textFieldList) {
        List<TextField> updatedTextFields = new ArrayList<>();
        try {           
            for(TextField textField:textFieldList) {
                TextField textFieldObj = textFieldRepository.create(textField.getDatasource(), textField.getStructure(), textField.getTextLimit(), textField.getType(), textField.getSymbols(), textField.getObfuscate(), textField.getColumnLabel(), this);
                if (textFieldObj != null){               
                    messageService.informUser(String.format("Text Field value was successfully added"));
                    updatedTextFields.add(textFieldObj);
                }
                else {
                    messageService.raiseError(String.format("Adding text field value failed!.."));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            messageService.raiseError(String.format("Adding text field value failed!.."));
        }
        return updatedTextFields;
    }
```

Is there a way to pass a list as parameter? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though it's necessary to provide a supporting autoComplete or choices method as well.

Something like:

```
public List<TextField> addTextFieldValues(List<TextField> textFieldList) { ... }

public List<TextField> autoComplete0AddTextFieldValues(String search) { ... }
```

See [fundamentals guide](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#__ugfun_programming-model_actions_collection-parameter-types) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. The links seems to be broken. Can you please update the link

Comment: Link now fixed.